# How to customize toggle button in android?

Tags: android, styles, customization, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I've been trying to customize a toggle button to look like this, but it seems like i'm not getting anywhere.

[image]

Can anyone give me an idea or any kind of tutorial on designing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for :

[image]

First create a `ToggleButton` XML :

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/follow"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#61849f"
    android:checked="false"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textOff=" FOLLOW "
    android:textOn=" FOLLOWING " />
```

Java :

```
toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.follow);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (isChecked) setUnfollow();
            else setFollow();
        });
```

The `setFollow` & `setUnfollow` methods :

```
private void setUnfollow() {
    toggleButton.setChecked(true);
    toggleButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    toggleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.border));

}

private void setFollow() {
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    toggleButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fill));
    toggleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_24, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Finally The fill.XML and bordre.XML (create these file in the drawable folder)

**Border.XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#61849f" />
</shape>
```

**Fill.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#61849f" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Yes! This is perfect.Thank you very much.